# Split a string with numbers and letters

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have strings with letters and numbers mixed. I would like to split them and make a sentence from them.

```
a<-"DiabetesTestInPast12months"
b<-"SmokingMorethan12PackYears"
c<-"30MinsOrLessExercise"
```

I would like to get :

```
a<-"Diabetes test in past 12 months"
b<-"Smoking more than 12 pack years"
c<-"30 mins or less exercise"
```

I couldn't figure out a way to extract the number inside a vector using `stringr`'s `str_extract_all`.

Comment: I noticed the you have `Morethan` in string `b`.  wouldn't that be `More Than`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd try:

```
#combine all the string in a vector
a<-c(a,b,c)
gsub("(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])","\\1 \\2",
     gsub("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z0-9])","\\1 \\2",a,perl=TRUE),
     perl=TRUE)
#[1] "Diabetes Test In Past 12 months" "Smoking Morethan 12 Pack Years" 
#[3] "30 Mins Or Less Exercise"
```

Simplifying a little:

```
gsub("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])"," ",a,perl=TRUE)
```

gets the same output.

Note that `Morethan` cannot be split because there's no way to know that are separate words (`MoreThan` would).

Answer (score 0):

I have working on c#.
Please use below code to you can split string as per your requirement.

```
       `if (str.IsAllUpper()) return str;
        return Regex.Replace(str, "([A-Z]{1,2}|[0-9]+)", " $1").TrimStart();`
```

Comment: Good solution, although it seems OP is working in R :)

Comment: I assume in R that is `ifelse(!grepl("[a-z]", x), x, trimws(gsub("([A-Z]{1,2}|[0-9]+)", " \\1", x), "left"))`?